# what is the difference between exec and dbus-launch?

Tags: d-bus, exec

If I start a process, particularly at session start, what is the difference between using `exec p` and `dbus-launch p`?

Answer (score 7):

`dbus-launch` is [DBus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org)-related. `exec` is a  shell built-in. See their manpages/help pages:

```
dbus-launch - Utility to start a message bus from a shell script.
exec - Replace the shell with the given command.
```

So... they basically do two different things... While both are expected to start program `p` passed as a parameter, you can read that in the case of `dbus-launch`, a few other things are done first:

> You may specify a program to be run; in this case, dbus-launch will launch a session bus instance, set the appropriate environment variables so the specified program can find the bus, and then execute the specified  program, with the specified arguments.

In this case, a DBus daemon instance is created prior to creating the process, and it should be running a secondary session bus, which is made available to the child process through environment variables.

Also note that in the case of `exec`, the current shell is replaced by a new program. `dbus-launch` will not replace the shell, and nor will the program you start alongside the daemon.